# Setting up jstree with ajax call in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, jstree

I am trying to set up Jstree with an ajax call. I thought the following would work:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mydiv').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': [@Model.Populate1("mycall?id1=3&id2=2&id3=101")]
```

where the model has:

```
  public string Populate1(string request )


   {
        string apiResponse = _myservice.GetData(request);
        return apiResponse;
     }
```

The apiResponse returns:

```
{"Id":3,"Parent":1,"Text":".node1"},
{"Id":1,"Parent":null,"Text":"node2"},
{"Id":15,"Parent":4,"Text":"node3"}
...
```

in the function but it comes out

```
{&quot;Id&quot;:3,&quot;Parent&quot;:1,&quot;Text&quot;:&quot;
```

... in the cshtml.

I thought that the above would work as the following did work:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#mydiv').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': [
                { "id": "3", "parent": "#", "text": "node1" },
                { "id": "40", "parent": "3", "text": "node2" },
                { "id": "500", "parent": "40", "text": "node3", },
```

I looked through all the documentation, stack threads and blog examples but still couldn't get it to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you need to output in Raw so the data is not encoded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Please add an answer (and accept it) so anyone else that stumbles on this question can see what changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

Adding @Html.Raw(Model.Populate1("mycall?id1=3&id2=2&id3=101")) solved the problem that it was returning "&quot".

I will try to post what I ended up doing when I have the time.